# Accessing to methods of case classes

Tags: scala, case-class

Why I can't access to methods of case class inside method of ordinary class when I initiate case class instance without `new` keyword? 
I.e. in the following code I get a compile-time error:

```
case class A() {
  private var _g = 12

  //getter-setter
  def g = _g
  def g_=(value : Int) = this._g = value
}

class B {
  def someMethod = {
    val aInstance = A
    aInstance.g = 4; // compile time error. Why?
  }
}
```

But if I add `new` keyword in `aInstance` declaration all work fine.

Error message is:

> Cannot resolve symbol g

Comment: Two things: First, please give the exact error. Second, why would you use a case class in this case?

Comment: @gzm0 please review updated question. I noticed that compile time error occurs only if I don't use the `new` keyword when creating case class instance. And to your second question: I don't know why I can't use case class it in this context, I'm beginner in Scala, so I write this code only for training

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an instance of class `A` with `A()` (which calls `apply` on `A`). Otherwise you're referring to the companion object itself.

Comment: thanks, you are right, now all works fine. But why you say `you're referring to the companion object itself`? I'm don't defined any companion object to `case class A` (i.e. I don't have any `object` with name `A` in same source file). It's mean that Companion objects always defined implicitly (unless I define it explicitly)?

Comment: Yes, a case class always comes with a companion object. If you want to add extra methods you can define it explicity, but it'll always have the `apply` method pre-defined.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You did not define `f` and meant probably `aInstance`.

```
class B {
  def someMethod = {
    val aInstance = A
    aInstance.g = 4
  }
}
```

Comment: It's typo in my question. Updated